# ACCESS VBA using using one more SQL QUERY in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba

I have two tables, one is std Table and KeyTable. 
I have to display the values of std table based on the condition of keytable.
For example, if the user selects ASIA, i have to create a sql query list of countries in ASIA and use this country values (example: INDIA,SRILANKA,BANGLADESH) as where clause in final query. I have tried building them. But I am not sure of the syntax

First query to filter out the values of ASIA

```
  strSQL1 = "SELECT keytable.[Lead Country] FROM keytable WHERE keytable.country='" &   lstcountry & "';"
```

Second query to display the values according to the first query in where clause

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Std Table] WHERE ([Std Table].Country IN (______));
```

The blank which i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine the two queries into one statement:

```
strSQL= "SELECT * " & _
"FROM [Std Table] " & _
"WHERE [Std Table].Country IN " & _
"(" & _
"  SELECT s.[Lead Country] " & _
"  FROM keytable AS s WHERE s.country = '" & lstcountry & "' " & _
")"
```

Comment: **@user3631655**, I modified my answer so the **final data comes from std table not from keytable**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
strSQL1 = "SELECT keytable.[Lead Country] FROM keytable WHERE keytable.country='" &   lstcountry & "'"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Std Table] WHERE ([Std Table].Country IN (" & strSQL1 & "));"
```

SQL Server would allow you to do that, I guess that ACCESS supports this, too.

**Please note that I removed the `;` in `strSQL1`!**

You could also provide a list of comma separated values:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Std Table] WHERE ([Std Table].Country IN ('DE','UK','JP'));"
```

Comment: Please use comments next time - don't edit the answer!